# Why does the d/dx operator output a derivative, whereas the integral operator accepts a differential?

Tags: differential-forms, differential-operators

Say I have differentiation operators $D_1$ and $D_2$, where $D_1$ is the normal gradient operator, and $D_2$ yields a differential

$$D_2 \Big{[} y = sin(x) \Big{]}$$
$$dy = cos(x) dx$$

It would seem like $D_2$ is the reverse of integration, not $D_1$, i.e.

$$\int [ \hphantom{.}dy = cos(x)dx \hphantom{.}] $$
$$ y = sin(x) + c$$

It recently occurred to me that the integration operator accepts a differential $df = {df \over dx}dx$, whereas the standard differentiation operator $D_2$ produces a derivative ${df \over dx} = {df \over dx}$.

I also noticed that chain rule is much easier when you have $y = \cos(u) du$, because you can use u-sub notation to do chain rule, i.e. $u = g(x), du = [...]dx$.

Is there a reason we don't use $D_2$? I.e. is it mathematically invalid to have an operator that takes that returns a differential $f'(x)dx$ instead of $f'(x)$. I've found one video that claims "d" is the differential operator whereas $\nabla$ is the gradient operator, but I can't find anything else online where it's recognized that there is some operator that returns differentials instead of derivatives?

I feel like many people first assume the integration operator is $\int (*) dx$ instead of $\int(*)$ since they are used to working with derivatives instead of differentials.

Comment: Both are used and both are useful. For instance, when working with differential forms, we use exterior derivative, $D_2$ in your notation. Just keep learning analysis and you will find out. (You will also learn that gradient and complete differential are *dual* to each other. But this is all much further down the road, when you study differential geometry.)

Comment: There are many derivative operators and there are many integral operators.  Some of both types act on differential forms and some of both types act on functions.  Which one is "correct" (which seems to be an underlying theme to your question) depends only on context.